Vim Search, Replace And Match Length Of Numbers By Appending Zeroes
I have a pattern in XML that I want to search and then replace by appending zeroes such that all the replaced numbers will have same length.
Pattern to search is as shown below:
<title>99
<title>1
<title>1232
<title>414212

After search and replace, the output should be as follows:
<title>0000099
<title>0000001
<title>0001232
<title>0414212

I can search and replace using below option:
:%s/title>/title>0/g

But, as expected, is only going to append only single 0 in front of the numbers.
Using Vim only, is it possible to execute a search and replace query, such that it not only appends zero but also as many so that all the occurrence have dynamic zeroes appended to match the length?
The size of the XML file I have is 3GB, so using Vim so far seems to be an efficient option.

You should never process XML using non-XML-aware tools.

How about XSLT? It is made for such tasks.

@YitzhakKhabinsky I'd love to see an XSLT based answer. OP could still filter their file through it from Vim.

The following command will pad all the numbers with leading zeros:
:%s/title>\zs\d\+/\=printf('%08s', submatch(0))

We match "title>" and then use the \zs atom to start the match, everything after this will be captured.
That's one or more digits \d\+.
We then use \= to substitute with an expression.
Our expression is the printf() function with a format of %08s, i.e. a string padded with zeros to eight characters.
Our second argument is submatch(0) which contains the digits we just captured.
Related documentation can be found in :help /\zs, :help :s\= and :help printf().
Note that some programs interpret numbers with leading zeros as octal and may stumble on something like 099.

An XSLT 3.0 solution (streamable if using a streaming processor):
<xsl:transform version="3.0" expand-text="yes"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" streamable="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="title">
   <title>{format-number(., '0000000')}</title>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>


Sorry but as somebody blissfully ignorant of XSLT, your code snippet without any explanation just isn't useful. I tried to run using xsltproc(which OP could conveniently run from Vim if they're so inclined) but apparently it supports only up to v1.1.

Someone asked for an XSLT-based solution so I supplied one. There are plenty of online resources for learning XSLT, this isn't the right place for a tutorial. There are many XSLT processors around including xsltproc that only support the ancient 1.0 level of the language, rather fewer that support more modern versions. A solution using XSLT 1.0 is easy enough, but a non-streaming 1.0 processor is unlikely to be able to handle a 3Gb file.

There are two issues with this answer: 1) The question was "Using Vim only ..." and you don't address this at all. You seem to imply to use another program yet refuse to tell us which one. 2) The syntax error in your original post leads me to believe that you never ran this, you never tested this and you wrote it using a non-XML-aware tool (which you should never do, according to your own words). I'm trying to verify your "solution" because that's what you obviously never did.

It's always difficult to know how to answer a question saying "do X using tool Y" when Y is the wrong tool for the job. I only gave an XSLT solution because someone asked for one, and I didn't read carefully enough to realise it wasn't the OP. I make no apology for the answer being a sketch; my policy when answering SO questions is to point people in the right direction, not to take them all the way to their destination.
